# Berry-Esseen function bound

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

By[Berry-Esseen theorem on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem) we know that
$$|F_n(x)-\Phi(x)|\le \frac{C\rho}{\sigma^3\sqrt{n}}$$
where $F_n$ is the cumulative distribution function given there.

However, in many important cases we expect $F_n(0)$ to be much closer or equal to $\Phi(0).$ For example if $p=1/2$ and $n$ is odd, then
$$F_n(0)=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} {n\choose k} p^k(1-p)^{n-k}=\frac{1}{2}=\Phi(0).$$

(By $F_n(0)$ above, I really mean we consider a slightly modified binomial distribution, but I hope this is clear.) Is there a better bound for $|F_n(x)-\Phi(x)|$ for the example above in terms of a function $E(x)$ that goes to zero as $x\to 0$ and achieves a maximum that is less than or equal to $\frac{C\rho}{\sigma^3\sqrt{n}}$? Is there a more general error term $E(x)$ that works for other binomial distributions?

Comment: What do you mean by a "modified binomial distribution"? Does it have zero mean?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant, so $F_n(0)=.5.$

Comment: So what is $F_n(x)$ for $x\ne 0$?

Comment: Just make the binomial distribution have zero mean by subtracting off the mean. The new $F_n$ adjusts accordingly. We can think of $B_{n,p}$ as a sum of bernoulli random variables. Instead of summing $X_1+\cdots +X_n,$ sum $(X_1-\mu)+\cdots +(X_n-\mu).$

Comment: By the way -- every definition I'm referencing is from Wikipedia. That is, $Y_n= (X_1-\mu)+\cdots +(X_n-\mu)$ and the rest is the same as wiki.

Comment: Then why $F_n(0)=1/2$?

Comment: Let me try another way: I have $n$ many i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables $X_i$ with mean zero and variance 1. They are defined by $1$ with probability $1/2$ and $-1$ with probability $1/2.$ I want to look at the distribution function of $Y_n$ from Wikipedia, which is a normalized sum of these $X_i$'s. The distribution function will be such that $F_n(0)=\Phi(0)$ if I sum an odd number of them, and something very close to $\Phi(0)$ if I have an even number. Is there a more precise formula for this case that describes the error of $|F_n(x)-\Phi(x)|$ near the origin?

Comment: For $n=10$ your summation yields [0.62](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+(10+choose+k)*0.5%5Ek*(1%E2%88%920.5)%5E(10%E2%88%92k)+,k%3D0+to+10%2F2)

Comment: Please check for $n$ odd (it's Always $.5$). As $n\to\infty,$ for $n$ even it also goes to $.5.$

Comment: This is such a waste of time. I said check n odd...sum (9 choose k)*0.5^k*(1−0.5)^(9−k) ,k=0 to 4

Answer (score 1):

For a sequence of zero-mean i.i.d. r.v.s $\{X_i\}$ with variance $\sigma^2$ and finite third moment $\gamma_3$,
$$
|\mathsf{P}(S_n/(\sqrt{n}\sigma)\le x)-\Phi(x)|\le \frac{C\gamma_3}{\sigma^3\sqrt{n}}\times \frac{1}{1+|x|^3},
$$
where $S_n:=\sum_{i\le n}X_i$ and $C>0$ is an absolute constant (see, e.g. [Chen and Shao, 2001](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/~lhychen/files/P25.pdf)). This bound is better then the uniform one for large values of $x$. However, if the distribution of $S_n$ is known, you may get better estimates.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. Is there anything else known as $|x|\to 0$?

Comment: Unless the distribution of $X_1$ is known, I doubt about the existence of such results...

Comment: But in this case the distribution of $X_i$'s is just Bernoulli. In this case is something known?